# Using conditionals in VB.NET to count

Tags: vb.net

I am running a program in windows forms visual basic and im trying to make multiple counters

Here is my code:

```
If txtAnswer.Text = nMathSum Then
        nCount = nCount + 1
        lblCorrect.Text = nCount
    ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathSum Then
        nIount = nIount + 1
        lblIncorrect.Text = nIount
    End If

    If txtAnswer.Text = nMathDiff Then
        nCount = nCount + 1
        lblCorrect.Text = nCount
    ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathDiff Then
        nIcount = nIcount + 1
        lblIncorrect.Text = nIout
    End If
```

It suppose to count how many times i answered correctly and incorrectly

The Counter for the Sum is working fine but the counter for the difference has a problem.
When i input the correct answer it goes to the incorrect label.

Comment: nIount and nIcount?  This happens when you pick weirdo identifier names.  Unweird ones that help you write bugfree code are GoodAnswerCount and BadAnswerCount.

Comment: which is it: nIount, nIcount or nIout ?  Hans Passant is right: use better identifier names!

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that txtAnswer will match both the sum and the difference. So, in your code, you will always have at least one of them incorrect.

Do you have some way of knowing if txtAnswer is supposed to match the sum or difference -- if so, check that before checking the answer.

**EDIT (to explain what I mean):** Something like

```
If operation = "+" Then
    If txtAnswer.Text = nMathSum Then
        nCount = nCount + 1
        lblCorrect.Text = nCount
    ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathSum Then
        nIcount = nIcount + 1       ' corrected this line to use nIcount
        lblIncorrect.Text = nIcount ' corrected this line to use nIcount
    End If
Else
    If txtAnswer.Text = nMathDiff Then
        nCount = nCount + 1
        lblCorrect.Text = nCount
    ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathDiff Then
        nIcount = nIcount + 1
        lblIncorrect.Text = nIcount ' corrected this line too
    End If
End If
```

Where operation is a variable that is set to "+" or "-" depending on whether the user is supposed to provide a sum or difference.

Comment: i guess i don't have a way of checking the sum and difference. Can you show me how to do it. I really need to finish this program

Comment: If you have no way of checking, there is no way to help you.  How does the user know whether they are providing a sum or difference? Whatever that is, use the same thing to figure out which answer to check against.

Comment: Is this what you mean by checking:

If txtAnswer.Text = nMathSum Then
                MessageBox.Show(" Correct, Nice Work ", "Your Answer is ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathSum Then
                MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect, Try Again ", "Your Answer is ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        End If

Comment: No. I tried to give more help in the comment.  You have to have something equivalent to `operation` in your program to check against -- not this exact code -- something equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling of `nIount` as `nIcount` in the seconf `Elseif`
Also as `nIout` in the last line.  Correct it as:

```
ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathDiff Then 
    nIount = nIount + 1 
    lblIncorrect.Text = nIount 
End If
```

This is assuming the first appearance (`nIount`) is the correct spelling.

Comment: VB.Net is not case sensitive.  This must be code that was just typed in the question, rather than copy and pasted.  The IDE would automatically correct the identifier name.

Comment: It's not about case sensitivity.  There is `nIount`, `nIcount` and `nIout` in the code in the question, most likely only one (at most two) of them is correct.